# Django permission check in template based on current user

Tags: python, django

Given some models:

```
class MailingList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Recipient(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mailingList = models.ForeignKey(MailingList)

class ListAdministrator(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    mailingList = models.ForeignKey(MailingList)
```

I would like to accomplish the following in clean MVC fashion without unnecessary code duplication: The currently logged in user may only delete a `Recipient` from a `MailingList` if he is listed as one of the `ListAdministrator`s or is a superuser.

The permission check should happen in two places:

1. The view `deleteRecipient(request, recipient_id)` should check for the required permissions before deleting a recipient. This part is easy, all the required information is right there in `request.user` and the `listadministrator_set` of `Recipient.objects.get(pk=recipient_id).mailingList`.
2. In a template listing all mailing lists with all respective recipients, only those which the current user is allowed to delete should display a "Delete Recipient" link next to them. This is where I struggle:

   - I cannot give the model a method `userMayDelete(self, user)` and call that method from the template passing the current user, because Django won't allow parameter passing from templates.
   - I cannot give the model a method `currentUserMayDelete(self)` without the user parameter because a model can't access the current user implicitly.
   - Passing the template two sets of mailing lists, those which the user can delete recipients from and those he can't, seems cumbersome. And it wouldn't allow a combined alphabetically sorted display of all list.

What is a clean (and preferably simple) way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using a templatetag?

Comment: You could include django.core.context_processors.request in your settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. So that request.user is available as a context.

Comment: Can't you pass the temple a dictionary containing a tuple of the list itself and whether or not the user can edit recipients?  So send in `lists = {'list1': (mailinglist1, False), 'list2': (mailinglist2, True), 'list3': (mailinglist3, True)}`. Then in your template while building the page (`{% for list in lists %}`) you can check if `lists[list][1]` is `True` and if so display the button?

Comment: Also from the template you could do `{% if user.is_superuser %} Show Button {% endif %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set additional attribute to the `MailingList` instance before passing it into to template:

```
def show_lists(request):

    username = request.user.username
    lists_under_control = [la.mailingList for la in
                           ListAdministrator.objects.filter(username=username)]

    mailing_lists = list(MailingList.objects.all())
    for mailing_list in mailing_lists:
        mailing_list.user_may_delete = (mailing_list in lists_under_control)

    return render(request, 'app/mailing_lists.html',
                           {'mailing_lists': mailing_lists})
```

And then use this attribute in the template:

```
<ul>
{% for mailing_list in mailing_lists %}
    <li>{{ mailing_list }}
        <ul>
        {% for recipient in mailing_list.recipient_set.all %}
            <li>{{ recipient.email }}
                {% if mailing_list.user_may_delete %}
                    <a href="{% url 'delete_recipient' recipient.id %}">
                        Delete recipient
                    </a>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The other (much worse) option is to create template filter and use it like this:

```
{% if user|may_delete:mailing_list %}
```